# Conditional string join with powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I'm currently working on a piece of code that assembles a string to identify an object based on various pieces of information. Some of that information might not always be available and I was wondering if there was clever way to make that assembly easier?

As an example we have the pieces `$a`, `$b` and `$c` that build the final identifier. Out of those `$b` might be empty and the final string should contain each components separated by a space. One option would be to add the additional space for `$b` to the string itself like this:

```
$a = "FirstPart"
$b = " SecondPart"
$c = "FinalPart"
Write-Output "$a$b $c"
#FirstPart SecondPart FinalPart
$b = ""
Write-Output "$a$b $c"
#FirstPart FinalPart
```

Another option would be to have a conditional (which can get rather complex and lengthy):

```
$a = "FirstPart"
$b = "SecondPart"
$c = "FinalPart"

if($b -eq ""){
    Write-Output "$a $c"
}else{
    Write-Output "$a $b $c"
    #FirstPart SecondPart FinalPart
}

$b = ""
if($b -eq ""){
    Write-Output "$a $c"
    #FirstPart FinalPart
}else{
    Write-Output "$a $b $c"
}
```

What actually would be quite need would be to use `-join` or maybe `-f` to get that conditional space if `$b` is not empty. Is there any way to do this or maybe another alternative? `($a,$b,$c) -join ' '` results in a double space if `$b` is empty.

Comment: If the parts themselve never contain spaces, you could use following regex `"$($a) $($b) $($c)" -replace '\s+', ' '`

Comment: That's pretty clever and could easily be changed to only react on consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = "FirstPart"
$b = "SecondPart"
$c = ""
$e = "last"

#put in array, and filter empty
$arr = ($a, $b, $c, $e) |  ? { $_ }

#print in space separed
Write-Output "$arr"
```